# How to change public IP address with browsermob-proxy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

When I check my public IP address through https://whatismyipaddress.com/ using browsermob-proxy, its the same as when visiting the site through my browser locally.  I'm wondering how would I configure browsermob-proxy to use a different public IP address?

```
    require 'selenium/webdriver'
    require 'browsermob/proxy'

    server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/Users/christopher/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
    server.start

    proxy = server.create_proxy #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Client:0x0000010224bdc0 ...>

    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new #=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000001022bf748 ...>
    profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

    proxy.new_har "google"
    driver.get "http://google.com"

    har = proxy.har #=> #<HAR::Archive:0x-27066c42d7e75fa6>
    har.entries.first.request.url #=> "http://google.com"
    har.save_to "/tmp/google.har"
```